# Imported products and categories system urls return 404

Tags: magento2, import, url-rewrite, product-urls

We are setting up import of products and categories from suppliers XMLs.
The idea is to have it automatic and we have successfully imported products and automatically generated categories using this component:

https://www.wyomind.com/magento2/mass-product-update-import-magento.html#documentation
- I can fully recommend it - their support is fast and great! :)

/end of commercial/

However I have noticed that I cannot access my products directly like:
`www.domain.com/catalog/category/id/123` or `www.domain.com/catalog/category/view/id/123`.
The same is with categories.

I know that URL Rewrites exists but as far as I understand they are so that I can rewrite "system urls" (like the ones above) into SEO friendly ones. In order for it to work "system url" should be working.. right?

Am I missing a step here?